# Hibernate - OneToMany - Several Columns

Tags: java, hibernate-annotations, hibernate-onetomany

I have those 2 tables Teacher and Contact, a teacher can have x Contacts. So here we are looking at a @OneToMany association.

Tables Structure:

> User [userid, username, email,...]
>   Contact [contactid, contactname, ref, reftype,...]

I want to load from my User Class all the user's contacts. To do that I would do a query like

```sql
Select * from contact as c WHERE c.ref=8240 AND c.reftype='T';
```

8240 being a random userid and reftype T being for Teacher. As this contact table is used as well for school contacts and/or anyother type of customer we could have. *The problem is I have no idea how to do this with Hibernate.*  Should I use embedbedId? Or a JoinColumns?

What I have done so far is to link my teacher to contacts having `contact.ref=teacher.teacherid` but what I want is :

```
contact.ref=teacher.teacherid AND contact.reftype='T'
```

How do I do that?

Here is my code
Teacher.class

```
private Integer teacherid;
private Set<Contact> contact;
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "teacherid", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getTeacherId() {
    return teacherid;
}

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
 @JoinColumns({
     @JoinColumn(name="ref"),
 })
public Set<Contact> getContact() {
    return contact;
}

public void setContact(Set<Contact> contact) {
    this.contact = contact;
}
```

Contact.class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contact")
public class Contact implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer contactid;
    private String contactname;
    private String contacttype;
    private String reftype;
    private int ref; 

    /*private Teacher teacher;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "ref"),
        @JoinColumn(name = "reftype")
    })
    public Teacher getTeacher() {
        return teacher;
    }
    public void setTeacher (Teacher teacher) {
        this.teacher= teacher;
    }
*/
    private Set<ContactItem> contactItems;
    private Set<ContactAddress> contactAddressess;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="contactid")
    public Set<ContactItem> getContactItems(){
        return contactItems;
    }

    public void setContactItems(Set<ContactItem> contactItems) {
        this.contactItems = contactItems;
    }

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name="contactid")
    public Set<ContactAddress> getContactAddressess(){
        return contactAddressess;
    }

    public void setContactAddressess(Set<ContactAddress> contactAddressess) {
        this.contactAddressess = contactAddressess;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "contactid", unique = true, nullable = false)
    public Integer getContactid() {
        return this.contactid;
    }

    public void setContactid(Integer contactid) {
        this.contactid = contactid;
    }

    @Column(name = "contactname", nullable = false)
    public String getContactname() {
        return this.contactname;
    }

    public void setContactname(String contactname) {
        this.contactname = contactname;
    }

    @Column(name = "contacttype", nullable = false)
    public String getContacttype() {
        return this.contacttype;
    }

    public void setContacttype(String contacttype) {
        this.contacttype = contacttype;
    }

    @Column(name = "reftype", nullable = false, length = 1)
    public String getReftype() {
        return this.reftype;
    }

    public void setReftype(String reftype) {
        this.reftype = reftype;
    }

    @Column(name = "ref", nullable = false)
    public int getRef() {
        return this.ref;
    }

    public void setRef(int ref) {
        this.ref = ref;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return "\n#"+this.contactname+" : ("+this.ref+"-"+this.reftype+") \n" 
                    +"#Items-----\n"+getContactItems()+"\n" 
                    +"#Address---\n"+getContactAddressess()+"\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the `teacher` a `user` (why are you showing the user table if not)? Do you have some kind of inheritance? Do you have a foreign key constraint on the `ref` column?

Comment: Even with your edits, I think my answer below is still generally correct.  You'll have to change the details to match your situation.

Comment: I personally think that there is something wrong in the design. Please clarify the relation between User/Teacher and Contact, this is important.

Comment: Sorry about his confusion.. Let's call my User.class Teacher.class, my table in db is teacher. About the relation between TEacher and Contact I think I was clear --> contact.ref=teacher.teacherid AND contact.reftype='T' In my contact table I don't have any FK, I just use an index 'ref','reftype' and obviously the PK contactid

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `Teacher` is a `User`, and that every user has `contacts`.

User.class

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", targetEntity = Contact.class, orphanRemoval=true)
@Cascade(CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Contact> contacts = new ConcurrentSkipListSet<Contact>();

//No setContacts here.
```

Contact.class

```
@ManyToOne
private User user;

public void setUser(User user){
this.user = user;
}
```

That's it.

Comment: I don't think your solution would work. As I don't see how you manage my special relationship between the User(Teacher) class and the Contact Class. The relationship being teacher.teacherid=contact.ref AND contact.reftype='T'.

Answer (score 0):

First, since there's a User table and no Teacher table (teachers seem to be a sub-set of user rows, denoted by a 'type' column) I wouldn't have a table of User and a Teacher model.  I would have only a User model instead. Hibernate is *much* easier if you do things the Hibernate way, which is one model per table with the model having the same name.  For example, if you do this, you can use a tool to auto-generate (reverse engineer) all your model classes.  This means a Hibernate tool will look at your tables, foreign keys, etc and generate *appropiate Java code* for your tables.  Very very convenient when you start making table changes.

Normally you'll reverse engineer the model classes. Since these are machine-generated you don't want to change them because the changes will be over-written the next time to reverse-engineer the models.   What I do for conditions such as yours is to create a class called a DAO - Data Access Object, or DAO.

```
public class UserDAO {
    public static User getTeacher(EntityManager em, Long id) {
        try {
        IForgotTheType query = em.createQuery("User from User user, Contact contact where contact.ref=user.teacherid AND contact.reftype='T' and User.id=:id");
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        return (User) query.getSingleResult();
        } catch (NoResultException e) {
           return null;
        } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
}
```

Obviously I am not sure about your table structure and column names but you get the idea.  You can see where I inserted your code into the query above.  Now you can get a teacher by simply calling UserDAO.getTeacher().  Use DAOs - otherwise you'll have Hibernate code *everywhere* in your code making maintenance more difficult.

[Check out section 3.4 of this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html_single/).

Comment: Thanks for That Tony, But I have some extra questions now. How would I access my contact object from my User(Teacher) object? And how does my User class look like? What kind of mapping should it be?

Comment: To access the contact object, you'll see Hibernate shine:  `userInstance.getContact();` returns an instance of Contact fetched from the database.

Comment: What should the mapping on user be?  Here's what I do. (That's a disclaimer!) 1. Define your database schema properly.  That means you'll have a User table with normal stuff in it including a primary key assigned by the database using a sequence.  There should be a contact_id column.  Then create a Contact table that has contacty stuff in it.  Define a foreign key using the user.contact_id column.  Then I reverse engineer the model.  I've done two large projects using Hibernate.  I have never hand-coded a model.  Reverse engineering is the win.

Comment: this becomes evident when you have to change a database table.  This *breaks* models.  Not to worry, just re-reverse engineer them.  We had a rule where I worked - never change a model by hand - because that allowed us to reverse-engineer as needed with no fear.  We did write a totally crappy pre-processor that jammed some stuff into each model such when to use cascading deletes etc.